# Using JGit : How to push a specific commit to a remote repo

Tags: git, egit, jgit

I need some JGit specific help please.

I am looking to the equivalent of the following using JGit library:

```
git push [remotename] [commit SHA]:[remotebranchname]
```

In other words: from a particular repo, I'd like to push everything upto a specific commit to another remote repo.

The `org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand` seems to be allowing me to specify only the remote name, but not the commit id or the remote branch name.

Could someone please point out what I am missing?

Comment: Update : I tried adding a RefSpec to the PushCommand with source = [commit id] and destination = [refs/remotes/__my__remote__name__/master], but this also hasn't helped.

Answer (score 1):

It got solved!!

Debugged inside JGit's transport / connection classes, looked at the advertised refs of the remote repo and found that as I was pushing my commits, the ref `refs/remotes/__my_remote__repo__/master` was moving but the ref `:refs/heads/master` was always staying unchanged. That was the reason, I wasn't seeing my changes reaching the GitHub.

I then switched from the earlier : `commitId + ":refs/remotes/__my_remote__repo__/master"` ref-spec to `commitId + ":refs/heads/master"` and it all works fine now!

The content now shows up correctly on https://github.com/my_remote__repo/commits/master.

Yay! Thanks for your help.